# Example of a complex manifold with certain curvature properties?

Tags: differential-geometry, examples-counterexamples, complex-geometry, curvature

Are there (nice) examples of a complex manifold such that the sectional curvatures through all the complex planes are non-positive but the sectional curvatures through the real planes are mixed?